# How do I launch GNU radio on Linux Fedora 24

Tags: linux, fedora, gnu, gnuradio

Sorry if the question appears basic, it is because I have only just started using Linux.

I have recently installed GNU and UHD from the following link,

http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/InstallingGRFromSource

typing

```
$ wget http://www.sbrac.org/files/build-gnuradio && chmod a+x build-gnuradio && \
  ./build-gnuradio
```

in the cmd line.

This was installed successfully for Fedora 24. However, I am struggling to find the application to run GNU Radio.

Can someone help me with this?

I installed GNU Radio in directory `\home\user_sl\Downloads\gnuradio-3.7.8.1`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: GNU Radio is a framework/ a library. you don't "run it". You build applications with it. GNU Radio does come with a flow graph designer and example applications, however! Read http://tutorials.gnuradio.org :)

Comment: @MarcB as GNU Radio is a development framework, this is kind of a corner case of that rule.

Comment: See: [**HowToUse gnuradio**](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/HowToUse)

Answer (score 0):

Try running `gnuradio-companion`.

GNU Radio itself is a framework, a set of libraries and a runtime.

Hence, you can use it to *build* applications. GNU Radio itself isn't an application that you can execute – there's applications that *use* it.

One of these applications is the GNU Radio companion. It's a tool to design digital signal processing flow graphs. Under the hood, it generates Python code, which uses the C++ GNU Radio library to set up the flow graph you designed. Neat!

I think the [official tutorials](http://tutorials.gnuradio.org) might be a very good place to start. Read them from front to back – they start off with a problem description, an intro to the companion, then Python programming topics, switch over to explain how to build GNU Radio C++ blocks if you should need them, then tackle real-world DSP programming problems.